# SAP HANA SQL how to convert Date and Time to timestamp

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to concatenate the `CreateDate` and `CreateTS` columns to make one Timestamp that contains the date and time.

Right now the only solution I reached is this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
        to_char(COALESCE("UpdateDate","CreateDate",'1970-01-01'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') || ' '||
        SUBSTRING (lpad(COALESCE("UpdateTS","CreateTS",0),6,'0'),0,2) || ':'||
        SUBSTRING (lpad(COALESCE("UpdateTS","CreateTS",0),6,'0'),3,2)|| ':'||
        SUBSTRING (lpad(COALESCE("UpdateTS","CreateTS",0),6,'0'),5,2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
    )  AS update_create
FROM OCRD
```

I found out that with `UpdateTime` column this code isn't working.
The big problem is that the date and time are distinct columns, and also it saves the time in different formats:

- **8** : it's 00:08:00 and not 00:00:08
- **223** : it's 22:30:00 and not 00:02:23
- **16321** : it's 01:63:21

Is there any already defined function to concatenate the date and time to get the real timestamp of the create/update?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

"UpdateDate" and "CreateDate" are stored as Date in SAP HANA, keeping year, month, day and 00:00:00.000 for time.

"CreateTS" and "UpdateTS" store just the time in format hhmmss as int. That means that 14:34:06 is stored as 143406. As an int, leading zeros are *not stored*.

The way to join date and time that worked for me is to create a varchar for date (format YYYYMMDD) and a varchar for time adding leading zeros. Then, creating a TimeStamp using date and time.

Solution:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR(COALESCE("UpdateDate","CreateDate",'19700101'), 'YYYYMMDD') || ' ' || LPAD(COALESCE("UpdateTS","CreateTS",0),6,0),'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
```

You can create a function to simplify this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_DATETIME(vDATE DATE, vTime INT)
RETURNS DT TIMESTAMP
AS
BEGIN
    DT := TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR(:vDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || LPAD(:vTIME,6,'0'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
END;
```

Then just use it: `SELECT "UpdateDate", "UpdateTS", TO_DATETIME("UpdateDate", "UpdateTS") as "UpdateDateTime" FROM OCRD`

EDIT: Sometimes CreateTS or UpdateTS are stored as HHMM instead of HHMMSS. Be careful with that either padding right with '00' or creating a new function for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns `"UpdateDate","CreateDate"` are stored as dates and columns `"UpdateTS","CreateTS"` store in format HHMMSS then you can try following:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( COALESCE("UpdateDate","CreateDate",'1970-01-01') || ' ' || TO_TIME(COALESCE("UpdateTS","CreateTS",000000)) )
```

Comment: hi @Konrad it stored as Integer in format HHMM so it means that 1 = 00:01 as described in my question, TO_TIME wil convert it to 01:00

Comment: But in your example you give 16321 -> it's 01:63:21 . So this is not HHMM format. And if 223 => 22:30, then how it's stored 02:23 ?

Comment: I think that the proble is this the column UpdateTime use forma HHMMSS but number 10 measn 10 seconds, but column UpdateTS the value 10 means 10 minuts